# Can't add element into container<T> with emplace new if T has explicit constructor

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, placement-new, explicit-constructor

I am writing a fixed size container type, with placement new.
When I was testing it I figured it out my "emplace_back()" like function does not compile if the type T has explicit ctor.

Here is a code sample (with missing delete call, etc):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct TestType
{
   explicit TestType(T value) // removing explicit makes it a compileable code
   {
      std::cout << value << std::endl;
   }
};

template <typename... Args>
void emplace(TestType<int>* buffer, Args&&... args)
{
     // placement new // compile time error in this line
    new (buffer) TestType<int>(std::forward<TestType<int>>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    TestType<int>* buffer;
    buffer = (static_cast<TestType<int>*>(::operator new(sizeof(TestType<int>) * 10)));
   
    emplace(buffer, 5);
   
    return 0;
}
```

The erros is:
" In instantiation of 'void emplace(TestType*, Args&& ...) [with Args = {int}]':
24:22:   required from here
16:64: error: no matching function for call to 'forward(int&)'"

There are some similar questions on stackoverflow, however these are mostly about std::map, probably my question is different. (And if not, I still don't understand what is going on.)

In the case of (e.g.) std::vector emplace_back() works with any T type with explicit ctor in them, why doesn't it work with my container type?
This compiles fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct TestType
{
   explicit TestType(T value)
   {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<TestType<int>> vector;
    vector.emplace_back(5);
     
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifying `TestType<int>` as template argument for `std::forward` as `std::forward<TestType<int>>(args)...`, means you're forwarding arguments as `TestType<int>`. The argument being passed is tried to be converted to `TestType<int>` implicitly, which doesn't work because the converting constructor is marked as `explicit`.

You should specify `Args` as template argument for `std::forward`, i.e. forward the arguments as:

```
template <typename... Args>
void emplace(TestType<int>* buffer, Args&&... args)
{
    // placement new
    new (buffer) TestType<int>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    //                                      ^^^^
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In my original example (with std::forward<TestType<int>>(args)...) if I remove the explicit keyword, in that case because of the implicit cast the default ctor is called and then the move ctor of TestType<int> is invoked as well. So this is another reason why std::forward<Args> should be used. Is that true?

Comment: @thamas Yes, for this case a temporary `TestType<int>` is constructed firstly via the converting constructor, then the temporary gets moved. Even [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) might be applied the construction of temporary is superfluous.